# why am i not able to get the return value of -1 when the condition is not met?

Tags: java, methods

why am i not able to get the return value of `-1` when the condition is not met?

```
package calcfeetandinchestocm;

public class Calcfeetandinchestocm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(4, 12);

        calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(-0.5);
    }

    public static int calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(double feet, double inches) {

        if (feet >= 0) {
            System.out.println("feet are " + feet + \
                               " and its equal centimeters are " + feet * 12);

        }

        if (inches >= 0 && inches <= 12) {
            System.out.println("inches are " + inches + \
                               "and its equal centimeters are " + inches * 2.45);
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public static int calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(double inches) {
        if (inches >= 0) {
            System.out.println("inches are " + inches + \
                          "and its equal centimeters are " + inches * 2.45);
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the return values, so how do you know you aren't getting -1 ?

Comment: You are never checking the return value.  What behavior do you want to happen when the inputs are bad?  By the way, one foot does not equal 12 centimeters :-)

Comment: yes! that's wrong. It was meant to be 1 foot equals to 12 inches

Comment: Your 2 methods will always return -1 at all. There is one and only one return statement in both methods.

Comment: You should return -1 from inside the brackets when condition is not met. And some success value at the end of method (what you are doing now with -1), like 0, to show success of the condition. Also, you need to store the value in some variable like @TacoWilson solution. Now you can check that value to determine if your method succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a variable equal to the function or do a system out print with the function as it's argument like:

```
System.out.print(calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(4, 12));
```

or

```
x = calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(4, 12);
System.out.print(x);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that helps

Comment: This is not a complete answer.

Comment: The answer is good but it will be more apt for acceptable if you can explain why in the first place the OP was not getting the desired output and then what you are providing in the answer to get the desired output. This will help OP in knowing his fault and not repeating it again.

Answer (score 1):

I'll address your question first.

> why am i not able to get the return value of -1 when the condition is not met?

You do not assign the result of the method call to a variable, so it's unclear how you recognize that you're not getting -1. In fact your methods as you have written them will **always** return -1 since that is the only return statement you have within the method body.

If you were to assign the result to a variable like this:

```
int centimeters = calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(4, 12);
System.out.println("4 feet 12 inches converted to centimeters is: "+centimeters);
```

The call to `System.out.println` above would output `4 feet 12 inches converted to centimeters is: -1`

There are a few other problems with your code:

1. You are not correctly calculating the result of the conversion.
2. You have a second method with the same name as the first but with fewer parameters and you're repeating part of the logic in the first method.

To address #1 - one foot is 30.48cm so obviously this line is incorrect:

```
System.out.println("feet are " + feet + \
                           " and its equal centimeters are " + feet * 12);
```

Furthermore one inch is 2.**5**4cm so your other calculation is also incorrect:

```
System.out.println("inches are " + inches + \
                           "and its equal centimeters are " + inches * 2.45);
```

I think it's probably obvious after what I said in the beginning, but you're also not returning the result of your calculation which is what I believe you intend to do. You need to convert feet to centimeters and inches to centimeters then return the sum of those two results.

To address #2 - your second method should probably not have the same name as it does not take a `feet` parameter at all.

Something like this would be more accurate:

`public static int calcInchesToCentimeters(double inches)`

Inside of this method you should not repeat the logic you have already written earlier in the code, instead just call your first method with 0 as the number of feet and pass the number of inches.

```
public static int calcInchesToCentimeters(double inches){
    return calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(0, inches);
}
```

Lastly some further reading I would suggest for you:

[Java Tutorial: Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

[The DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0):

Here in your code, it dose not depend on condition so either your condition is true or false it returns always -1 so, you just need to grab return value from function. Like,

```
int result = calcFeetAndInchesToCentimeters(4, 12);
System.out.println("Result is " + result);
```

it surely print -1.